# Call PHP rest webservice from ajax MVC asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

i am trying to call php rest webservice from MVC ajax but after calling it it is not going to call success i dont what i am missing here.

webservice required 2 paramaters my code

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://test.com/custom/",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: { "ReleaseVersion": "XXX", "ReleaseType":"XXX" },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("webservice called successfully");
    }
})
```

it tried using json.stringfy while passing parameters but it wont work.
is anyone how to solve this.
Environment: Visual Studio 2013 and MVC 4.0.

Comment: Add `error: ` function and see if you got any error in there.

Comment: @ramiramilu Error: Readystate=0,responcetext=undefined,status=0,statustext=networkerror. i got this information

Comment: if both `php service` and your `website` are in two separate domains, then you need to allow `CORS`. The error which you are getting is rither due to CORS or due to `Authentication/Authorization`. Were you able to send the request and response using fiddler or any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

set datatype in ajax call that is jsonp for calling cross domain webservice.

In php webservice code you have to add header before passing json.

as header content type=application/json, then and then only you will get json from php webservice in your ajax call.